# PHP pass an ID between scripts

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

I have a problem that I can't solve.

I am creating an `Android App` where there is a section showing user data.

The data is saved on a `MySql` database through `Register.php` and to get them use the `Show.php` file.

When I open the user activity in the app, there is a hidden field that contains the user's `id`, the app sends the id to the `Php` script and shows all the data of that user.

The problem is that the data is shown with a bit of delay, because it has to read the `id` from the app and show the filtered data.

What I would like is that in the `Php` file there was already the user `id`, so the display of the data on the app would be instantaneous, because so I already have the value of the variable that contains the `id` to use then in the `Query`.

To do this I thought of using [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

But it does not work.

In the `Register.php` file I inserted a session variable to store the value of the variable `id_restaurants` that I need in the `show.php` script to show that user's data through a `Query`.

But in the `Register.php` file it seems that the value of the variable `$ _SESSION ['varId']` is not saved.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the registration file: `Register.php`

```
<?php

session_start();


   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

       include_once("config2.php");

    $idUser = $_POST['idUser'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $restaurant = $_POST['restaurant'];
    $id_restaurant = $_POST['id_restaurant'];

    $_SESSION['varId'] = '$id_restaurant';


     if($name == '' || $surname == '' || $restaurant =='' ){
            echo json_encode(array( "statusr" => "false","message" => "Insert all data") );
     }else {

            $query= "SELECT * FROM Restaurants WHERE restaurant='$restaurant'";
            $result= mysqli_query($con, $query);


            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
               echo json_encode(array( "statusr" => "false","message" => "Name restaurant already exist") );
            }else{ 
             $query = "INSERT INTO Restaurants (idUser,name,surname,restaurant,id_restaurant) VALUES ('$idUser','$name','$surname','$restaurant','$id_restaurant')";


             if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){

                 $query= "SELECT * FROM Restaurants WHERE name='$name' AND surname='$surname' AND restaurant='$restaurant' ";
                         $result= mysqli_query($con, $query);
                     $emparray = array();
                         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
                         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                     $emparray[] = $row;
                                   }
                         }
                echo json_encode(array( "statusr" => "truer","message" => "Registered succesfully!" , "datar" => $emparray) );

            }else{
                 echo json_encode(array( "statusr" => "false","message" => "Error") );
            }

        }
                mysqli_close($con);
     }
     } else{
            echo json_encode(array( "statusr" => "false","message" => "Errore3") );
    }

 ?>
```

Here is the show file: `Show.php`

```
<?php
 session_start();

 include 'config.php';

 $conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);


 $idRestaurant = $_SESSION['varId'];


 if ($conn->connect_error) {

  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM Food WHERE id_restaurant ='$idRestaurant'" ;

 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows >0) {

     while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  $tem = $row;

  $json = json_encode($tem);

}

 } else {
  echo "No Results Found.";
 }
  echo $json;
 $conn->close();
 ?>
```

And then you think there's a better way to pass the id between `Php` scripts?

I listen to you willingly.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using SESSION variables is the right way to pass variables between scripts. First, make a change in the code at Register.php: $_SESSION['varId'] = $id_restaurant; (notice I removed the single quotes to store the value of $id_restaurant) - see if this makes a difference.

Comment: @verjas I thank you for the help, but it doesn't work.
The $ _SESSION ['varId'] variable on the Show.php file is empty.